How to handle multiple file with java SpringBoot on REST API
I literally got stuck on 1 problem, i cant save the data that i send to endpoint. Assume in this case i have a entity / model named PKS. i have also created the services, controller and the DTO, but in this case the PKS must be have a attachment files to be created, the db relation is like in the image i attach with this link the code for PKS is
@Entity
@Table(name = "pkss")
public class PKS {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TypeChoices partnershipType;

    private LocalDateTime submissionDate = LocalDateTime.now();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BudgetTypeChoices budgetType;

    private String budgetNumber;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MethodeTypeChoices partnershipMethod;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MaterialTypeChoices materialType;

    private String title;
    private String background;
    private String note;
    private String partnershipCandidate;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatusChoices status;

    private int positionLevel = 1;

    private boolean isStopClock = false;
    private String responseText;
    private String approvalNote;
    private String pksNumber;
    private LocalDateTime approvalCompletionDate;

    @ManyToOne
    private Functionary officialUndersign;
}

the relation i can tell to you are

PKS - Attachment : one to many
PKS - RAB : one to many
PKS - Scope : one to many
PKS - official undersign : many to one

my point here is how to handle the file, so i want to store the attachment in file system and i store the path and filename in database. this is my attachment models and pks
@Entity
@Table(name = "attachments")
public class Attachment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String filename;
    private String filePath;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mou_nda_id", nullable = true)
    private MouNda mouNda;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pks_id", nullable = true)
    private PKS pks;

public class AttachmentDTO {
    private String file;

    // Getters and Setters
    public String getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String getFilePath(String typeDir) {
        return "/home/bintang/media/attachments/" + typeDir + this.file;
    }
}

and below is the pksdto
public class PKSDTO {
    private Long id;

    private String base;  // Assuming you have a similar enum or String for 'base'
    private LocalDateTime submissionDate;  // DateTime field for submission date
    private String partnershipTitle;  // Title for the partnership
    private String background;  // Background information
    private String note;  // Notes
    private String partnershipCandidate;  // Candidate for the partnership
    private String status;  // Status of the PKS
    private int positionLevel;  // Position level
    private boolean isStopClock;  // Stop clock flag
    private String responseText;  // Response text
    private String approvalNote;  // Approval note
    private String pksNumber;  // PKS number
    private LocalDateTime approvalCompletionDate;  // Approval completion date
    private Long userId;  // ID of the user
    private Long officialUndersign;  // ID of the official undersign

    private List<RabDTO> rab;  // List of RAB
    private List<ScopeDTO> scopesPks;  // List of scopes
    private List<AttachmentDTO> attachmentsPks;  // List of attachments
}

and this is in the service
public ResponseEntity<PKS> createPks(PKSDTO pksDto) throws IOException {
        // Check if userId is provided
        if (pksDto.getUserId() == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User ID must not be null");
        }

        // Find user
        User user = userRepository.findById(pksDto.getUserId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User tidak ditemukan"));

        // Create and set up the PKS object
        PKS pks = new PKS();
        pks.setUser(user);
        pks.setTitle(pksDto.getPartnershipTitle());
        pks.setBackground(pksDto.getBackground());
        pks.setNote(pksDto.getNote());
        pks.setStatus(StatusChoices.valueOf(pksDto.getStatus()));
        pks.setSubmissionDate(pksDto.getSubmissionDate());
        pks.setPositionLevel(pksDto.getPositionLevel());
        pks.setResponseText(pksDto.getResponseText());
        pks.setApprovalNote(pksDto.getApprovalNote());
        pks.setPksNumber(pksDto.getPksNumber());
        pks.setApprovalCompletionDate(pksDto.getApprovalCompletionDate());

        // Save the PKS object to the database
        pks = pksRepository.save(pks);

        // Save scopes if present
        if (pksDto.getScopesPks() != null) {
            for (ScopeDTO scopeDto : pksDto.getScopesPks()) {
                Scope scope = new Scope();
                scope.setScopeName(scopeDto.getScopeName());
                scope.setPks(pks);
                scopeRepository.save(scope);
            }
        }

        // Save RAB if present
        if (pksDto.getRab() != null) {
            for (RabDTO rabDto : pksDto.getRab()) {
                RAB rab = new RAB();
                rab.setCustomer(rabDto.getCustomer());
                rab.setType(TypeChoices.valueOf(rabDto.getType()));
                rab.setRevenue(rabDto.getRevenue());
                rab.setCost(rabDto.getCost());
                rab.setCostDesc(rabDto.getCostDesc());
                rab.setPks(pks);
                rabRepository.save(rab);
            }
        }

        // Save attachments if present
        if (pksDto.getAttachmentsPks() != null) {
            for (AttachmentDTO file : pksDto.getAttachmentsPks()) {
                String fileName = FileNameUtils.generateSafeFileName(file.getFile());
                String filePath = baseDir + fileName;

                // Save the file to the file system
                // SaveFile.save(file, filePath); // You may need to implement SaveFile.save() method

                // Create and save the attachment object
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                attachment.setFilePath(filePath);
                attachment.setFilename(fileName);
                attachment.setPks(pks);
                attachmentRepository.save(attachment);
            }
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(pks, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

my question are :

how to create the controller with @PostMapping and the attachment is multiple file in the body? My references are from django serializer below.
how do i save in the file system and save the path in the database?

# serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import *


class ScopeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Scope
        fields = ['scope_name']


class AttachmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Attachment
        fields = ['file']


class RabSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RAB
        fields = '__all__'


class MouNdaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    scopes_mou = ScopeSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    attachments_mou = AttachmentSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Mou_Nda
        fields = '__all__'


class PKSSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rab = RabSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    scopes_pks = ScopeSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    attachments_pks = AttachmentSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = PKS
        fields = '__all__'


